# Asserting whether object exists in an ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to assert whether object exists to use it.

This is on method 1:

```
            List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();

            x.add(protocol);
            x.add(c.get(0).getStatus());
            if (!c.get(0).getReply().isEmpty()) {
                x.add(c.get(0).getReply());
            }
```

And on method 2 (where that list is sent to):

```
                    for (SolicitationDatabase solData : my) {
                        solData.setStatus(data.get(1));
                        if (data.get(2) != null) { //this makes it crash
                            solData.setReply(data.get(2));
                        }
                    }
```

Stacktrace:

```
05-31 08:47:06.766 8892-8892/com.example.ga.realm3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.example.ga.realm3, PID: 8892
                                                                 io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
```

How can I know if record 2 exists in the list?

Comment: what is data? the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the condition as:

```
for (SolicitationDatabase solData : my) {
     solData.setStatus(data.get(1));
     if (data.size() > 2 && data.get(2) != null) { //this makes it crash
         solData.setReply(data.get(2));
     }
}
```